# Problem with NSNotification & Dismissing modal View Controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller, nsnotifications

So, I have a tabbarcontroller, and I pass a notification to `dismissModalViewController` when a particular `tabBarItem` is touched.

It is working well and the modal View Controller is dismissed. But I want to change it in a particular way, and it does not work as I expect it to...

I have the observer initialized before the notification is posted. These are the tabBarItems -

```
NSArray *viewControllerss = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: myProfileDataViewController, 
sampleViewController,reminderInfoViewController, nil];


[self.tabBarContr setViewControllers:viewControllerss animated:YES];
self.tabBarContr.selectedIndex = 2;
```

I send a notification on the `viewWillAppear` of `sampleViewController` and when I choose that tabBarIcon, it dismisses the TabBarController.

BUT I want the `sampleViewController` to be on the left most of the `UITabBar`.

And so I add it like

```
 NSArray *viewControllerss = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: sampleViewController,
 myProfileDataViewController, reminderInfoViewController, nil];
```

THIS DOES NOT DISMISS TAB BAR CONTROLLER.

***Note:*** *Please see the order in which NSArray is initialized.*

*The notification is posted in the `viewWillAppear of`sampleViewController` and observer in the respective  view controller which presents the modal view controller*

Answer (score 0):

Could you put a NSLog right before you post the notification?

See if you get any output when the app loads.

EDIT: Adding onto the answer based on your response

In your sampleViewController could you try this:

Make it conform to the UITabBarControllerDelegate. Your sampleViewController class interface should be something like this:

```
@interface SampleViewController : UIViewController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

Then in the .m of your sampleViewController, in the viewDidLoad, set the delegate to be the sampleViewController (self in this case)

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{   
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Assuming you have a reference to your tabBarController somewhere

    [self setDelegate:self]; // try this line or the line below
    // [[self tabBarController] setDelegate:self];

    // The rest of your drawing code here
}
```

Now implement the delegate method somewhere inside the sampleViewController .m file.

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    // I've included this to see if this method actually gets called or not.
    NSLog(@"Dismissing modal view controller");

    // check to make sure sampleViewController tab was pressed by checking 
    // the class type of the viewController parameter being passed in

    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[SampleViewController class]]  
    {
        // I assume you have a pointer reference to that modal view controller 
        // you want to dismiss
        [self dismissModalViewController:theUnwantedViewController animated:YES];
    }


}
```

See if that works.

Comment: I always NSLog everywhere. Notifications are sent, observers are ready. Modal View Does not dismiss when `sampleViewController` is added first to the array

Comment: So you got an output from that NSLog? I was wondering if switching between tabs will trigger the viewWillAppear method.

Comment: Yes, it did not trigger the viewWillAppear.

Comment: Could it be that when the app first loads, the first tab bar controller is already being loaded, the viewWillAppear fired once but nothing happens. Then when your app finish loading, you see tab bar controller 2 (due to your tabbar select index 2 code) and when you tried to switch back to sampleViewController, it doesn't count that as the view appearing and so viewWillAppear never got fired, hence why your notification to dismiss the view controller never got called ?  I think I recall there being a protocol delegate method that lets you do something when a tab bar is selected.

Comment: You are EXACTLY RIGHT with that. How can I go about that ?

Comment: I've edited my original answer to include a possible solution